# What is a safe and efficient diy or commercial solution to convert 120VAC to 120VDC?

Tags: led, voltage, transformer, switching-regulator

I want to power a series system of ~4 x high power leds, each with a forward voltage of 30-34V.  I understand that I can use a diode bridge rectifier to convert AC to DC, but this will have a frequency component that is undesirable.  There are ways to get rid of this frequency component, but they seem either too advanced or dangerous for my level of expertise.  Since the desired DC voltage is very close to the supplied AC mains voltage, there should be a highly efficient solution available, but in my searches I am getting mostly AC-AC transformers, and AC to variable DC power supplies (usually low voltage DC).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Safe is out of the window if you want 120 volts dc as an output. You might as well use a capacitive dropper to a bridge rectifier and smoothing capacitor.

Comment: A bridge rectifier will output the _peak_ voltage of an incoming AC signal. 120Vrms from the wall has a peak voltage of about 170V, so that's what you would get from a bridge rectifier. As Andy says, safe is definitely out the window.

Comment: example already exists on circuitlab https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=46tndq

Comment: Thanks Jon - X-mass tree lights are a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you rectify (X) volts AC into a capacitor, you'll get (X * sqrt(2)) volts DC.  That's because AC mains are usually a sinewave specified in RMS, and the rectifier takes the peak.  If you delete the cap, then the RMS output should be closer to the RMS input, but that only plays nice with approximately resistive loads, unlike your LED's.  Probably the most practical solution, given the research that you've done already, is to use a ~35V DC supply and run your LED's in parallel.

---

If you insist on the series string, you might try a bridge rectifier into a series inductor and *then* a parallel capacitor.  This would give you better filtering than the cap alone, without adding a huge amount of resistive losses.  (though you'll still have some because the inductor also has some resistance)

Comment: Thanks.  You and Dwayne make good points about the rectified peak voltage, which will be much higher than 120 (closer to 168V without capacitor and 150V with capacitor and ripple).   I'm going to go with the 35VDC supplies for now and study safe ways to do the filtering at lower voltage.

Answer (score 2):

How much current?

One easy solution is to do a bridge rectifier on the incoming AC mains, followed by a filter inductor, followed by your filter capacitor and load.  The size of the filter inductor and capacitor depends on your current consumption and how much ripple you can tolerate.

The really *ROUGH* rule of thumb is that the average voltage (with ripple) for a full-wave rectified and filter capacitor is about 1.25 times the incoming RMS voltage.  The peak voltage is about 1.4 times the incoming voltage, but ripple drops the average down to about 1.25 times.

On the other hand, adding a sufficiently-large inductor between the bridge rectifier and filter cap / load drops the average voltage down to about 1.0 times the incoming voltage.  The resulting DC has significantly less ripple.

Comment: The current can be up to 2A.  I am afraid to use a large capacitor without proper grounding and discharge considerations.  Given my experience level I think I will study your approach using low voltage AC and go with 35V DC power supplies in the mean time as AaronD suggested.  It will be much less efficient than desired but at least I can be safe (in the absence of a commercial solution).  In the mean time I will study IC filtering approaches as well as grounding/discharge strategies.